# Collectors.summingInt() and Collectors.joining()

Tags: java

I have a `Cat` class, which has `String name` and `int tailLength` fields and `String getName()` and `int getTailLength()` methods.  `Cat` instances are placed in `List<Cat> cats`.  My question:

Why does this work fine:

`int tailsEndToEnd = cats.stream().collect(Collectors.summingInt(Cat::getTailLength); //(1)`

and this does not:

`String allNames = cats.stream().collect(Collectors.joining(Cat::getName); //(2)`

I know that I can collect the cats' names like this:

`cats.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(Cat::getName, joining(", ")); //(3),`

just curious as to why (2) does not work, seen that it is perfectly analogous to (1), regardless of how the output would look (no comma, etc).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All `Collector.joining` variants return a `Collector<CharSequence, ?, String>`, which means they can only operate on a `Stream<CharSequence>`.

When you use `Collectors.mapping(Cat::getName,joining(", "));`, `mapping` transforms your `Stream<Cat>` to a `Stream<CharSequence>`, which allows that `Stream` to be processed by `joining()`.

You can't directly process the `Stream<Cat>` with `joining`, since it has no variant that accepts a mapping function to convert your `Cat`s to `String`s.
All the arguments of `joining` are `CharSequence`s, and serve as either delimiter, prefix or suffix.

This is unlike `summingInt`, which accepts a `ToIntFunction<? super T>` mapper function to map the elements of your `Stream` to an `int`.

Answer (score 3):

Eran's answer basically sums it up, I just wanted to add that in your specific case, a more idiomatic (& definitely more readable) way to achieve what you want would be:

```
String catNames = cats.stream().map(Cat::getName).collect(Collectors.joining());
```

This way each operation can be examined independently and so is easy to read & understand:

1. Map a list of cats to a list of their names
2. Join the list of cat names into a single string

Whereas in your 3rd example you're performing both of the operations inside of `collect`, which is less natural to read.

Comment: You're not wrong, I prefer this as well. However, the analogous way to sum int is `stream.mapToInt(Cat::getTailLength).sum()`.

Comment: Agreed. You definitely want to split each data transformation step into separate stream operations because it becomes so much easier to debug, to spot any bugs and just to maintain in general. And also since Java streams combines operations whenever it can under the hood, you don't even lose out on performance (i.e. in the example you provided, the mapping & summing happens in one pass of the data, instead of over 2 separate passes as it might seem at first glance).

Answer (score 0):

Something I haven’t seen addressed is that [the Collectors.joining method that accepts one argument](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/api/java.base/java/util/stream/Collectors.html#joining(java.lang.CharSequence)) only accepts a CharSequence as an argument:

> public static … joining(CharSequence delimiter)

(What matters here is not the return type, but the method parameter definition.)

`Cat::getName` is not a CharSequence, it’s a method reference (which can be interpreted as a Function).  It will never be a suitable argument for that method.

As others have said, you would need to map to a String first, then call Collections.joining, either with zero arguments, or with a single delimiter argument.